# Jquery .load using javascript variable

Tags: jquery

I have this code tested in w3school

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<b>Books</b>

<br>

Author<br>
<div id="author"></div>
<br>


<script>
var getvar = "books.xml";

$( "#author" ).load("books.xml author");


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working... now I need to replace the books.xml with the variable getvar

This code is not working

```
    <script>
var getvar = "books.xml";

$( "#author" ).load("getvar author");


</script>
```

Any help how to replace with the getvar variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code from

```
$( "#author" ).load("getvar author");
```

to

```
$( "#author" ).load(getvar + " author");
```

Additionally, move your script inside document ready block.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.
Got this message - 504 - Gateway Timeout

Comment: The above should have worked. You should also move your script inside the the document ready block.

Comment: @syntaxcode - Apologies but not clear with your comment on head tag

Comment: For some reason, when I placed the script into the head and followed your  code, then it worked.

Comment: The above code will work fine even when you place your script in body tag. However, as I mentioned, you should move your script inside document ready block. For reference -  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/